# Alert dialog text not visible when colorprimary is white

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, textcolor

in my app theme colorPrimary is white. So, textcolor of alertdialog is not visible below Android N. Then, I create a custom theme for alertdialog but still not working.

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomActivityAnimation</item>
</style>
```

This my custom alert dialog theme. My dialog has arrayadapter.

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

I used this theme following code.

```
private void showAccountSettingsPopUp(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
    }
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.add(getString(R.string.blocked_list));
    stringList.add(getString(R.string.edit_my_profile));
    stringList.add(getString(R.string.delece_acc));
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList);
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, BlockedUserActivity.class));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, EditProfilActivity.class));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    showTwoButtonAlert(getString(R.string.are_you_sure), getString(R.string.delete_acc_text), false);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the theme you've defined for your alert dialog to that activity as a app:popupTheme
e.g. in xml

```
<LinearLayout
...
        app:popupTheme="@style/AlertDialogTheme"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
...
/>
```

Comment: This is not working. Still same result. I found solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use style like

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFCC00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/theme_color_blue</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not theme. This is related to arrayadapter list item. I created textview which color is black and set it to arrayadapter listitem like below.

I use this,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.textview_arrayadapter, stringList);
```

instead of

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList);
```